# rendering collection of webpages in Shiny application

Tags: r, shiny, html

I am trying to render a collection of webpages as tiles in Shiny.  I have css codes to create the tiles.  While the program runs without any error messages, I am not getting the pages populated in the screen.  Instead, when I click the tile it opens a new tab and populates the page.  The following is the reproducible df

```
structure(list(author = c("DHYANI1811", "THE_PARALLEL_ME", "IMRITIKTHAKUR", 
"IMRITIKTHAKUR", "IMRITIKTHAKUR"), article_url = c("http://twitter.com/Dhyani1811/statuses/667885170591006721", 
"http://twitter.com/The_Parallel_Me/statuses/667883209607114752", 
"http://twitter.com/imRitikThakur/statuses/667880559704600576", 
"http://twitter.com/imRitikThakur/statuses/667880186638012416", 
"http://twitter.com/imRitikThakur/statuses/667880150910963712"
), sentimet = c("neg", "pos", "neu", "pos", "pos")), .Names = c("author", 
"article_url", "sentimet"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


df 

runApp(list(ui= fluidPage(
    titlePanel("opening web pages"),

    mainPanel(
        htmlOutput("test")
    )
),
server = function(input, output, session) {

    k <- reactiveValues(active = df,
                        first.load = FALSE)

    output$test <- renderUI({
        if(k$first.load){
            js$showInfo()
            k$first.load = TRUE
        }

        if(length(k) == 0)
            return(h2("No possible data"))

        fluidRow(
            column(12, id="columns",
                   lapply(df$article_url, function(i) {
                       a(box(width=NULL,
                             title = HTML(paste("<div class='image-wrap'><img src= ''",
                                                df$img[df$article_url == i],
                                                "'class='",
                                                df$img[df$article_url == i],
                                                "'></div>", 
                                                "<strong>By:",
                                                df$author[df$article_url == i],
                                                "</strong><br>",
                                                '<span style="font-size: 11pt;">Sentiment: ',
                                                df$sentimet[df$article_url == i],
                                                '</span>'
                             ))
                       ), href=paste(i), target="_blank") 


                   }
                   )))
    })   
})
)
```

I have changed `title = HTML(paste("<div class='image-wrap'>`  to `HTML(readLines` or have used `return(HTML(readLines` and various other similar combination.

Comment: Your example isn't working for me. Have you tested it on a fresh session? Is any other package needed?

Comment: @Molx Apologies....Have missed adding library(shinydashboard)  which I have done so now

Comment: did not work for me as well; df <- a does not help us since a is not defiend

Comment: a is nothing but df here, it can be ignored

Comment: @Molx @MLavoie When I checked the elements after the page loads, I am seeing the following `<img src="class=" '="">`, indicating that the loop is not rendering the url from the dataframe...any thoughts